# What is the best way to secure sqlite database file from users deletion?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I deployed a sample java swing program and put data in local sqlite file. I created database manually. If I delete database file and run my program, program create this database but without tables. What should I do in this case? I also think that if user deletes sqlite file in program files it will be very bad situation - data will lost. Therefore, should I make back up? How else can I protect database file from deletion?

Comment: You can use something like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to create the tables automatically when you initialise the database connection

Comment: *" also think that if user deletes sqlite file in program files it will be very bad situation - data will lost"* - dumb user, no seriously, dumb user. At some point you can't take into account everything the user "might" do

Comment: Yes, you can keep backups, but their is still the possibility that you'll lose data.  You need to be making decisions about when to do the backups, how to do the backups (SQL commands or manual copy) and verify the backups (MD5). It's a lot of work to guard against the user doing something they shouldn't. So you need to weigh the amount effort against the possible risk and make decision which best meets your particular needs

Comment: Ok I understand enough so I must create my database not manually if I first time run program it create new database with tables and i should backup for user might delete file and if this file deleted I ask options to user for load from backup or like  first time run program with new database- tables ,thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

An SQLite database file is just a file, so if you want to protect it, you have to use the mechanisms of the operating system to protect this file.

However, if your program must be allowed to modify this file, and if your program runs with the rights of the user, then the user is also allowed to modify this file by other means.

You should simply check that the database file contains correct data when the program starts. (You will probably need to do this anyway after the next update of your program.)

Comment: But i think I should backup from being deletion at least